# определение границ

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

как в регулярном выражении задать границы слова

есть строка: "твориться", при использовании такого выражнения:

```
s/([^абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]*)(действовать|совершать|творить|создавать)([^абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]*)/$1make$3/g;
```

получается "makeся"

причем, сам элемент паттерна - может быть как и в начале строки, так и в конце и между другими словами/символами

Comment: `\b` группа должна отвечать за границу слова

Comment: благодарю, но в perl "\b" не работает с кириллицей

Comment: если речь про perl - стоит добавить соответствующую метку к вопросу

Comment: я надеялся что может быть есть другое решение без "\b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказали выше, в новых версиях Perl есть паттерн \b (Unicode break). Для того, что бы он отработал надо включить прагму utf8. 
То есть, в начале скрипта надо указать что-то вроде

```
use v5.20;
use utf8;

for my $line (("text test", "texttest")) {
    say "bingo for $line!" if $line =~ m/\btext\b/;
}
```

Если же вы не хотите использовать \b, то самое простое решение будет заменить его на \W (то есть, не слово). Но, это костыль :)

Или замените не обязательные вхождения по краям слова на обязательные:

```
s/([^абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+|^)(действовать|совершать|творить|создавать)([^абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+|$)/$1make$3/g;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59970/discussion-on-answer-by----).